# Eclipse RCP Inject into instance of IWizard

Tags: eclipse, dependency-injection, eclipse-rcp

I am trying to inject some of my Wizard's fields.

I can successfully inject my own OSGi DS using the following helper class:

```java
public class UtilRCP {

public static void inject(Plugin plugin, Object object) {

IEclipseContext serviceContext = EclipseContextFactory.getServiceContext(plugin.getBundle().getBundleContext());
ContextInjectionFactory.inject(object, serviceContext);
    }
}
```

Other Services from the RCP ecosystem such as PartService or MApplication fail to be injected (null / no actual value was found for the argument "MApplication").

Here is the code

```java
public class MyWizard extends MyAbstractWizard implements IImportWizard {

    private MyWizardPage page;
    @Inject
    private EPartService partService;
    @Inject
    private DatabaseProvider databaseProvider;
    @Inject
    private MApplication application;

    public MyWizard() {
        System.err.println("Create");
        System.err.println(databaseProvider);
        System.err.println(partService);
        System.err.println(application);
    }

    @Override
    public void init(IWorkbench workbench, IStructuredSelection selection) {

        UtilRCP.inject(Activator.getDefault(), this);
        System.err.println("Init");
        System.err.println(databaseProvider);
        System.err.println(partService);
        System.err.println(application);
    }

    @Override
    public void addPages() {

        super.addPages();
        page = new MyWizardPage();
        addPage(page);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean performFinish() {

        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The service context has very limited contents and is not suitable for use like this.

In a 3.x style wizard like this you can get the workbench context from the `IWorkbench` object using:

```java
@Override
public void init(IWorkbench workbench, IStructuredSelection selection) {

  IEclipseContext context = (IEclipseContext)workbench.getService(IEclipseContext.class);
```

Note that when a dialog is active there is no active 'part' (because a dialog is not a part). This can cause problems with various APIs. In particular the application (workbench) part service will give an exception complaining that there is no active part.

You can get a working part service by explicitly getting the part service for the top level window using:

```java
@Inject
MApplication application;
@Inject
EModelService modelService;

MWindow window = (MWindow)modelService.find("top level window id", application);

EPartService partService = window.getContext().get(EPartService.class);
```

I believe the top level window id for a 3.x RCP is "IDEWindow".

If its an E4 application, you can find the **main window id** in your **Application.e4xml**.

Comment: That works like a charm, thanks so much!
Could you maybe explain why it is a difference to get the Context by calling
IEclipseContext serviceContext = EclipseContextFactory.getServiceContext(plugin.getBundle().getBundleContext());
and
IEclipseContext serviceContext = workbench.getService(IEclipseContext.class);

Comment: When using the PartService, I get the following exception:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Application does not have an active window
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ApplicationPartServiceImpl.getActiveWindowService(ApplicationPartServiceImpl.java:43)

Comment: There are many different contexts, one for each part, one for the application and many others. The service context is a specialised context for OSGi services and isn't suitable for other uses.

Comment: When a dialog is active there is no active part. The application part service doesn't work in this case because it needs to delegate to the active part. I have added some code to the answer which can find the main window part service which should work (I have only used this code in a pure e4 app, not a 3.x app).

Comment: by the way, how can I do this in an "e4-way"? Our application is e4 based.

Comment: If your app is pure e4 you shouldn't be able to use `IWorkbench` or `IImportWizard` or the import wizard extension point at all! Ask a new question explaining exactly what you are doing.

Comment: Maybe its not pure ;) But as I understand it, things like Wizards and Preferences are not available in a pure e4 app.

Comment: OK, thats maybe another topic. Anyways, it works now, ive done some minor changes to the answer. Many thanks for fast helping!